# Is there a specific reason as to why Docker isn't a service on the dbus?

Tags: systemd, docker, d-bus

I was looking at the services available on the dbus/sd-bus. I noticed though that some services existed (e.g. NetworkManager, system-logind, wpa_supplicant), Docker was missing.

I was wondering why they made a decision to not also integrate with the dbus/sd-bus, assuming we view Docker as a core utility in this day and age. Is there a reason Docker preferred to use their own API? Are there issues I'm not seeing with such an integration?

Edit: I'm just trying to understand why, besides the extra work, the Docker devs would choose to not integrate with the dbus. This is a question about dbus mostly, with the main study case being Docker.